# Removing periods from strings inside tables. easy. - java

Tags: java, string

I have this string I got from a table via 'string.split(" ");' the problem I have is one of them should include a period. How would I go about searching for this period. I do know I have to search for it because I code in Lua. Though we used String.find() methods.

What is the way I would remove a period from a string in a String[] table?

Thanks in advance :)

This is for school.

Comment: What defines the difference between a period that is delimiting and a period that is part of a value?

Comment: [`String#indexOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28int%29) or [`String#contains`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I'm not that clever with RegExp, but you could...

```
String s = "This.is.a.test";
while (s.contains(".")) {
    s = s.replace(".", "");
}
System.out.println(s);
```

I'm sure there's a wonderful single line RegExp to do the same thing

**Updated based on comments**

Because `String` is not mutable, you will need to reassign it back to the original array

```
String[] apples = {"one", "two.", "three"};
for (int index = 0; index < apples.length; index++) {
    String s = apples[index];
    while (s.contains(".")) {
        s = s.replace(".", "");
    }
    apples[index] = s;
}
for (String s : apples) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Comment: Another question would be to this subject is could I make string.split split each letter by "" when I do this?

Comment: Okay, you lost me there.  You want to splat a `String` on the quote character?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you have a String that you've split by delimiting on a space.  You now want to search for a period in the resultant array of Strings.

```
for(String s : stringArray) {
    if (s.contains(".")) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes! Thanks. Now how do i remove that period?

Comment: Looking at your code I only took part of it. The s.contains. Now I was thinking that if I had:
        apples = {"one", "two.", "three"}
It would return true.

Comment: @user2262111 [`String#replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28char,%20char%29)